# Fabricjs - clarification with extending toObject method with additional attributes

Tags: fabricjs

I got the following code form fabric JS site as mentioned this code is for extending rectangle class with additional property, But I can't understand how it works clearly can someone please explain this piece of code

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect();

rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });
  };
})(rect.toObject);

canvas.add(rect);

rect.name = 'trololo';
```

Comment: you are overriding `toObject` method of rect object, and this will applicable for that object only not to all `fabric.Rect()` objects. `toObject` method calls when you are serialising the object, in your case it will add `name` as a additional property with your object.

Comment: yes i understand that  i want to know what this line does                       
                                                                                                            return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });

Answer (score 1):

This code is not extending the `toObject` method of all the fabric.Rect(s).
Is overwriting the `toObject` method of your particular instance of fabric.Rect, hosted in the `rect` var you just created.

```
(function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });
  };
})(rect.toObject);
```

`fabric.util.object.extend` is like `lodash merge`. It takes an object as first argument and adds to it the properties of the object from the second argument.

`to.Object.call(this)` is calling the function toObject that is the first argument of the wrapping function, that is rect.toObject before being modified.

Fabric support this functionality without modifying the code but using:

rect.toObject(['name']);

Or a nicer way to write this would be:

```
var originalToObject = fabric.Rect.prototype.toObject;
fabric.Rect.prototype.toObject = function(additionalProps) {
  var originalObject = originalToObject.call(this, additionalProps);
  originalObject.name = this.name;
  return originalObject;
};
```

In this case can be more clear.